# Error while executing robot framework scripts in Edge browser(Windows 10)

Tags: windows, selenium, webdriver, robotframework

I'm trying to automate the web application using Robot Framework in Windows 10 OS with Edge browser. I have downloaded the Microsoft Edge Webdriver from  the link "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/"
and placed it in the path "C:\Python27\Scripts"

[Error Message.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oi9bz.jpg):
When I run the script, it shows the error message:

> The ordinal 870 could not be located in dynamic link library C:\Python27\Scripts\MicrosoftEdgeWebdriver.exe

Any suggestions on resolving this error would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Edge Webdriver is bound by version to the Windows 10 build that it is executing on.

I have seen the error message:

"The ordinal 870 could not be located in dynamic link library"

while attempting to run the Release 14393 (3.14393) version of the MicrosoftWebDriver on version 1507 of Windows 10.

For me, this could be resolved by downloading the 1.10240 version of the MicrosoftWebDriver or updating my system to version 1607 of Windows 10.